# Edit checkbox options that already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` that has_many `Categories`.

These Categories are represented as checkboxes.

What I want to happen is on their settings page, it should show all the checkboxes with the ones they have previously selected already checked.

It should also allow them to check new ones, or uncheck existing ones to update their profile.

This is how I initially generate the checkboxes when they first select the categories:

```
      <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
              <span class="three columns alpha">
          <label for="regularCheckbox">
        <%= check_box_tag "user[category_ids][]", cat.id, false %>
            <span class="gig-check"><%= cat.name %></span>
          </label>                  
        </span>
      <% end %>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this usually:

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
  <% checked = @user.categories.include?(cat) %>
  <span class="three columns alpha">
    <label for="regularCheckbox">
      <%= check_box_tag "user[category_ids][]", cat.id, checked %>
      <span class="gig-check"><%= cat.name %></span>
    </label>                  
  </span>
<% end if @categories %>
```

Comment: I am getting a 'nil' error when no categories have been specified on the `each`. How do I address that within your solution?

Comment: You can add the `if @categories` as I added in my answer. But usually, when no categories are found with `Category.find` you should have an empty array [], which does not make the `each` break.

Comment: Am not using `Category.find`. Just using `Category.all`. Isn't `Category.find` deprecated in Rails 3.x? Well...in the `find(:all)` sense..I mean.

Comment: Yes, you're right, `find` is used to find a specific row. I was giving an example, `Category.all`, `Category.where(...)` or anything else would give you an empty array when nothing is found.

Comment: Just tried this, and it's not 'checking' the boxes for existing categories. Just displaying blank checkboxes.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I suggested a change to your answer. `cat.id == (current_user.categories.include?(cat))` was always returning false, because of different outputs. `cat.id` returns an integer and `current_user.categories.include?(cat)` is `truthy`. Nice elegant solution though. Once you accept my edits, I will mark as accepted.

Comment: the Tin Man and xdazz refused the edit! I don't know why. It seems OK to me!

Answer (score 2):

The definition of check_box_tag is:

```
check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
```

So, the third parameter is if the checkbox is checked or not. You are passing it always as 'false'. Instead you should have something like this:

```
<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
      <span class="three columns alpha">
      <label for="regularCheckbox">
        <%= check_box_tag "user[category_ids][]", cat.id, @user.categories.include?(cat) %>
        <span class="gig-check"><%= cat.name %></span>
      </label>                  
    </span>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I am getting a 'nil' error when no categories have been specified on the `each`. How do I address that within your solution?

Comment: @marcamillion -> `@categories.each` should do nothing if `@categories` is an empty Array. But you can do: `<% unless @categories.blank? %> Here the code I posted before <% end %>`